# Two different recurrence formulas

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

In Henri Cohen Number Theory Volume II we have :

> Definition $9.1.6$. We define the tangent numbers $T_k$ for
> $k>0$ by $$T_k = 2^{k+1}(2^{k+1}-1) \frac{B_{k+1}}{k + 1}.$$ Thus
> $\,\tanh(t) = \sum_{k \ge 1} T_{2k−1} t^{2k−1}/(2k − 1)!$.

> Corollary $9.1.7$. The tangent numbers satisfy the recurrence $$\sum_{j=1}^k {2k-1 \choose 2j-1} T_{2j−1} = 1$$ for $k > 0$, and in particular $T_{2k−1} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $k \ge 1$.

No proof for this is written expect for a hint $\,\cosh(t) \tanh(t) = \sinh(t)\,$ which implies $$\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{2k}{2^{2j-1}(2k-2j+1)} {2k-1 \choose 2j-1} T_{2j−1} = 1$$ for $k > 0$ and not the book's recurrence formula!

I checked several times and my result is correct. I checked numerically as well and both book's recurrence and my recurrence formulas give the same $T_i$'s.

My question:

I am very much interested in how the book's recurrence formula holds, but after lots of attempts I failed. How to reach from $\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{2k}{2^{2j-1}(2k-2j+1)} {2k-1 \choose 2j-1} T_{2j−1} = 1$ to $\sum_{j=1}^k {2k-1 \choose 2j-1} T_{2j−1} = 1$?